# Cannot disable emacs automatically changing how lines are indented

Tags: emacs, auto-indent, major-mode

I would like to turn off `electric-indent-mode` for all major modes in emacs from my `.emacs` file.

I have tried adding these to my `.emacs` file (each separately):

```
(electric-indent-mode -1)

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook (lambda() (electric-indent-mode -1)))

(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda ()
    (add-hook 'electric-indent-functions
      (lambda () 'no-indent) nil 'local)))
```

None have worked on my simple `.cpp` test file.

To be a little more clear, here is what is happening:

This:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
             std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

The line with `std::cout << ...` re-alignes itself to have 2 spaces when I press either the second `:` or the `;`

I want to be able to control how my files are indented by entering the characters myself, not by emacs changing them. I believe this is with disabling `electric-indent-mode` (hence my attempts to disable), but there may be another way.

I am using emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.9)

Comment: Please report this as a bug.  Note that the only thing you (should) need is `(electric-indent-mode -1)` since that's a global minor mode.  After that, all the rest you added has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are barking up the wrong tree.  In my Emacs (which is admittedly an older version), colon is bound to `c-electric-colon` in C++ mode.  This behaves "electrically" regardless of `electric-indent-mode`.  Read its documentation; there seems to be a variable `c-electric-flag` which you can set to `nil` to disable this behavior.

If all else fails, and you want to keep the other features of C++ mode, rebinding the keys you don't want to behave "electrically" in that mode seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that I was barking up the wrong tree and this problem only existed with the `c-electric-flag` on and only in C++ mode. Setting it to `nil` worked. :D